# Outlook 2007 (on 64 bit OS only?) hangs while editing messages

Tags: exchange-2003, outlook-2007, windows-7

I have a recurring issue with Outlook 2007 completely locking up while editing a message. The environment is Exchange 2003 and the client OS is both Windows 7 64 and Windows XP 64. It seems to happen more often on the Windows 7 machines. The symptoms are usually the same. When editing a message, usually very early in the process, Outlook 2007 continues to draw it's windows but the mouse just disappears when hovering over any of them. Outlook.exe uses 100% of one core and stops responding to all inputs.

I've googled extensively and tried a few things, like deleting and recreating the MAPI profile, but nothing has done any good. I don't know what to try next.

Comment: I think it was a corrupt profile. I created a new Windows user profile and the problem hasn't recurred since.

Comment: Or not. It has returned even under the new profile.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a flakey add-in causing the problem. Try starting Outlook with the /noextensions switch.

See below for more command line switches for Outlook 2007 which may help with troubleshooting.
[Command-line switches for Microsoft Office Outlook 2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-outlook-2007-HP001218589.aspx)